# Buttons under Filter not appearing in Ag-Grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

**Edit**: [Here's a plunkr of my issue](https://plnkr.co/edit/3LmHueyc0WboJqS9)

Ag-Grid provides an option to set 4 buttons under the provided filters. These are Apply, Clear, Reset and Cancel buttons. [Here is an example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-provided/#apply-clear-reset-and-cancel-buttons) . I am trying to show the **Apply** and **Reset** buttons on the provided Number Filter but it's not showing. The filter is working fine but the buttons does not appear.

Here's my column defition:

```
filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
filterParams: {
    buttons: ['apply', 'reset']
},
```

And here's how it looks. No button is shown
[image]

**NB**: I am using **Ag-Grid 23.0.0** Community Edition with **Angular 9**.

Comment: Please share an example, a plunker or something like that..

Comment: I'll add on and update the post

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/3LmHueyc0WboJqS9 here's the plunkr

Comment: The difference between your issue's example and the working example you added is in the index.html file. if you'll copy both variables: systemJsMap, systemJsPaths from the working example to your issue's example (paste it to index.html - override the variables there) it will works.
So as I understand its something with your files there. try to find out exactly the differences between these two fields.

Comment: I'm using Angular + typescript. The plunkr example presented in ag-grid seems to be using systemJs so I've modified it to show my issue. Ive noticed that it's working in 23.2 but not in 23.0 which is what I'm using. I suppose the version I'm using is causing the problem

Comment: The buttons were added in v23.2.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have updated to newest version
"ag-grid-angular": "^23.2.1",
"ag-grid-community": "^23.2.1",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^23.2.1",

now it works with Angular 9 and TS

Comment: The buttons appeared after I upgraded ag-grid versions too. So, I guess it was version issue (without any further evidence)

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, I'm on angular 8 version ^22 and have this issue also. Sheesh I want my hour back! :D Did you find this issue reported somewhere here https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues ?

Comment: Using version ^21 with angular 9 also no working with the filter buttons, need to update to ^23.2.1 in order to use

Comment: Thanks for the solution. After update The css is changed at my end. any suggestion!